# Why the unreferenced object is not collected by GC?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Maybe it's me, but I'm wondering about this (strange) behavior.

Consider the below snippet, which is the minimum Console program to illustrate the effect.

```
class MyClass { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            var x = new MyClass();
            var y = new MyClass();

            x = null;
            GC.Collect();

            Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

When the program halts for a keypress (or also by placing a breakpoint), the memory profiler shows that there are two "MyClass" instances still referenced.

The `GC.Collect()` does not help, nor running the program as "Release".

Shouldn't the unreferenced `MyClass` instance be collected as soon, at least by forcing the GC collection?

NOTE: the larger Console app involves a bunch of threads producing data, and the MyClass-like instance act as consumers. The instances are referenced via `WeakReference`, but it seems that's not an issue. The problem is that I am not able to trash a consumer by running all my test lifecycle in the Main method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried  to use `GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();`? GC may run asynchronously in non-blocking mode

Comment: And `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`

Comment: For you all, I tried many GC pattern, including the suggested Collect-WaitForPendingFinalizers-Collect, but without any result.
I'd love if anyone could try the same, because I'm seriously thinking to some problem on my platform...

Answer (score 1):

GC.Collect(); does not guaranteed to be completed immediately , it starts a background thread and returns immediately so the moment profiler checks it , it may be not collected.

Answer (score 1):

`GC.Collect()` runs asynchronously. [In order to run it synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/748777/1156119) you need to call:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```