# Does garbage collection run immediately after GC.Collect()?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, garbage

The question is just for research purposes.

I've read many books about C# and this question always comes to my mind. What I understood that C# is managed code and all garbage collection occurs when CLR decides when to run garbage collection. Let's start.

Let's imagine that I have simple class `Student`:

```
public class Student
{
    public int IdStudent { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
This is row1:    Person person = new Person() {IdPerson=1, Name="Bill", SurName="Collins"};
This is row2:    System.GC.Collect();
This is row3:    string str="Hello World!";
    }        
}
```

Please, approve or reject my suppositions:

1. Am I right that garbage collection is not run immediately at **row2**?
2. `GC.Collect()` is just a **request** to make a garbage collection which DOES NOT RUN IMMEDIATELY at row2. This row **maybe executed** in x milliseconds/seconds. 
   In my view, method `System.GC.Collect();` just says to garbage collector that garbage collector should run garbage collection, but **real garbage collection may occur in x milliseconds/seconds**
3. Only garbage collector knows when garbage collection will be run. And If there is free space in Generation 0, then garbage collection will not occur in the **row2:** `row2: System.GC.Collect();`
4. **It is not possible to run garbage collection immediately as we are programming in managed environment and only CLR decides when to run garbage collection.** Garbage collection can be run in x milliseconds/seconds or garbage collection **maybe not run** cause there is enough space in generation 0 to create new objects after calling method `GC.Collect()`. What programmer can do is just ask CLR to run garbage collection by method `GC.Collect()`.

**Update:**

I've read [this msdn article about `GC.Collect Method ()`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). However, it is unclear to me when real clearing of unreferenced objets is started. MSDN says:

> GC.Collect Method () forces an immediate garbage collection of all 
>   generations.

However, in **Remarks** I've read this one:

> Use this method to try to reclaim all memory that is inaccessible. It
>   performs a blocking garbage collection of all generations.

5. I am confused by this **"Use this method to TRY"** and I think that garbage collection **may not occur** cause **CLR** decides that there is enough space to create new objects. Am I right?

Comment: Oh it definitely runs, but are you asking if it collects something specific?

Comment: @Sayse yeah, does GC collect unreferenced objects?

Comment: The [GC.Collect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation contains some of the answers..

Comment: Please read the remarks of the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)..

Comment: Outside of some very specific situations (mostly, micro-benchmarking), if you find `GC.Collect()` in your code, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: _"[Garbage collection occurs when one of the following conditions is true...* The system has low physical memory....* The memory that is used by allocated objects on the managed heap surpasses an acceptable threshold...* The **GC.Collect method is called**...Before a garbage collection starts, all managed threads are suspended **except for the thread that triggered the garbage collection**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx)"_.  There's a ton more techno babble on this site all rather interesting :)

Comment: @Stepup, There are two GCs and from your code, I belive you want to know about Workstation GC. Which minimizes pauses by running concurrently during full collections?

Comment: None of the questions you ask are about the contracts you have with the GC. Different GC implementations are free to do whatever the hell they want :) There's a reason for that - it's one of the parts of the runtime that can benefit greatly from optimization, and the more things you have in the contract, the less optimizations you can legally do. If you have `GC.Collect` anywhere in your production code, you're breaking things. Just ... don't. Also, when running in a debugger, `person` is not deemed unreferenced at the point of your `GC.Collect`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER**

Calling `GC.Collect()` will do a complete garbage collection and wait for it to finish, but it will NOT wait for any pending finalizers to run.

**LONG ANSWER**

You're partially right in your suppositions because the GC for running finalizers runs in one or more background threads. (But see the footnote at the end of this answer.)

However, it *is* possible to wait for a complete GC to finish by calling [`GC.WaitForFullGCComplete()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647068%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.waitforpendingfinalizers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) after you have called `GC.Collect()`:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
```

However, be aware that *The thread on which finalizers are run is unspecified, so there is no guarantee that this method will terminate.*

Note that you should not normally use the GC in this way; I assume you have a special case that you need to address, or you are doing this for research purposes.

The only valid case I've seen for this is when an application is closing, and you want to (try to) ensure that all finalizers have been run - because, for example, they will flush log files etc.

As noted above, this still doesn't guarantee that all finalizers have been run; it's just the best you can do.

In answer to your point (5):

The documentation for GC.Collect() states:

*Forces an immediate garbage collection of all generations.*

So this *will* force a GC.

The documentation also states:

*Use this method to try to reclaim all memory that is inaccessible.*

The use of the word "try" there merely means that even if a full GC is run, not all inaccessible memory will necessarily be reclaimed. There are several reasons that can occur, for example, a finalizer may block.

**Footnote**

.Net 4.5 [allows you to specify whether `GC.Collect()` is blocking or not](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138633%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In fact, the documentation for `GC.Collect()` states that *It performs a blocking garbage collection of all generations*, which would appear to contradict my statements above. However, there seems to be some confusion as to whether this really is the case.

See for example [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748777/run-gc-collect-synchronously).

The answer is this: `GC.Collect()` will *by default* wait for all generations to be GCed, but it will NOT wait for pending finalizers, which are always executed in a separate thread.

Hence if you do not need to wait for finalizers, you ONLY need to call `GC.Collect()` and you do NOT need to wait for anything else.

Comment: this question is just for research purposes. Please, answer at the fifh question of UPDATE section of my question.

Comment: to conclude `GC.Collect()` will not force IMMEDIATE garbage collection after calling `GC.Collect()`? just `yes` or `no`

Comment: @StepUp `GC.Collect()` will force an immediate garbage collection and wait for it to finish (full garbage collection) EXCEPT for pending finalizers, which are run in a separate thread. I've put something at the start of my answer to stress this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two GCs and from your code, I belive you want to know about Workstation GC. Which minimizes pauses by running concurrently during full collections? The Workstation GC uses the second processor to run the collection concurrently, minimizing delays while diminishing throughput. We should be only worried about GC behaviour if server GC is not doing its job properly. If you add GC.collect() in your code as per workstation GC, that may be useless on Server GC.

The server GC is designed for maximum throughput, and scales with very high performance. Memory fragmentation on servers is a much more severe problem than on workstations, making garbage collection an attractive proposition. In a uniprocessor scenario, both collectors work the same way: workstation mode, without concurrent collection

> I am confused by this Use this method to TRY and I think that garbage collection may not occur cause CLR decides that there is enough space to create new objects. Am I right?

For workstaion GC, GC.Collect will start collecting as soon as possible, you can assume safely it collect immediately.